# How do I redirect page using Javascript to page.php#sample

Tags: php, javascript

I want refresh page using javascript and go to div id.

Example what I have done is

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '" . $url . "/page.php#contact';</script>";
```

Example the `#contact` div is on half of page and it's not working, unless I hit the enter button and it goes to the `#contact`.

```
<div id="contact">Contact</div>
```

If with php can be done

```
header('Location:/page.php#contact');
```

Let me know the correct way to do this

Comment: if you use PHP don't forget since it's writing headers, the header function MUST be called before any other output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically your script should work. At least when I tried it, it seemed to work without too many problems. However, remember that if you're just putting the javascript on the page like that, then the browser may run it immediately without waiting for the entire page to load. My point being, that if you output the javascript *before* you actually place the DIV tag on the page, the browser may not see the div tag yet and can not scroll the browser there.

You want to either make sure that the script is outputted after the DIV in the HTML souce or that the javascript is run after the page has loaded by using something like this for example:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload = function () { top.location.href = '" . $url . "/page.php#contact'; };
</script>";
```

Also, if you want to refresh the page, then this will not work, because the browser assumes you just want to go the location of `#contact` if the url is the same as the current url.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
location.href = '#contact';
```

Comment: I tried.. Example the `#contact` div on the half of content but it won't work unless we hit the enter button on keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your page has the bookmark or anchor defined near the contact div

in order to move on to #contact div, you must have anchor [contact] or bookmark defined there.

contact

then it should redirect to that respective location

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $url; //for debugging purpose only, to see if you are writing this right!
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
location.href = '" . $url . "/page.php#contact';
</script>";
```

No `top` needed before `location.href`.